# Insert into table

Tags: sql, postgresql, insert

I want always to insert into `mylog` table regardless whether user exists in `myusers` table or not, so I'm using:

```
insert into mylog (c1,c2)
  select t.userx, coalesce(ig.webuser,'X') from (
    select 1,1,'username'::text as userx
  ) as t
  left join myusers ig on t.userx = ig.webuser
;
```

Is there shorter query which does same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement

```
INSERT INTO mylog (c1,c2) 
VALUES('username', coalesce((SELECT webuser 
                             FROM myusers 
                             WHERE webuser='username'),'X'));
```

would do the same but shorter.
imo your statement makes no sense. You always log 'username','X' or 'username','username'

Comment: it is simplified query, so yes, as it looks now it doesn't make much sense.